# How to open browser using execlp native function in C

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

Hi I am working on android app in which I am using one native c library to achieve some functionality in my app.

I am opening a web browser from native c code but here when developer specified a package name and activity name of default browser then it works well but those phones which does not have default browser then it does not work like Motorolo, Nexus phones etc. They have google chrome browser, xiaomi have their inbuilt different browser.

Then I tried to look a c files of that library project there I found developer specified package name and activity name of browser that looks like only the reason it does not work in some phones.

```
if (version >= 17 || version == 0)
{
    execlp("am", "am", "start", "--user", "0", "-n",
            "com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity",
            "-a", "android.intent.action.VIEW",
            "-d", url, (char *)NULL);
}
else
{
    execlp("am", "am", "start", "-n",
            "com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity",
            "-a", "android.intent.action.VIEW",
            "-d", url, (char *)NULL);
}
```

Can we have simple action.View instead of specifying any browser package name and activity name. Let OS handle it so whatever browser is available on device then our source code will open that browser. If so then what would be param value of this `execlp`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just run the data file and let the OS decide which utility to use?

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry I didn't get you :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use command without "-n ..." like

> am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com

this will open a default browser on android or show select browser dialog.